# How do you find the position of a point on a matrix

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry

I have a basic peice of algerbra I need to solve. Unfortunatly I didn't pay attention in high school.

I have three points two of which I know A and C.

`C = 421,361`

`A = 50,50`

B should be 50 units away on the diagonal line from A but still draw a straight line through C and A for example:

[image: Example]

Any help is appreciated a formula or insight would be great, I have absolutely no idea how to go about this?

I apologize if my tags are inaccurate I know almost nothing about mathematics.

Comment: Sorry. You're going to have to do a better job of explaining the question. A and C are given?  C is the center of a rectangle? All we know about B is that it is 50 units away from A? Is it known to be on the line segment joining A and C (but yet you're telling us that C isn't known?)?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure how else to explain this, it is as simple as it looks I know A 50,50 and C 421,361 and I draw a line between them. 50 units from A on that line is where B should be, How do I calculate B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The horizontal distance (along $x$) from $A$ to $C$ is $421-50$, which is $371$.

The vertical distance (along $y$) from $A$ to $C$ is $361-50$, which is $311$.

So, by Pythagoras' theorem, the diagonal distance is $\sqrt{371^2 +311^2}$. Doing the arithmetic, we get:
$$
\sqrt{371^2 +311^2} = \sqrt{137641 + 96721} = \sqrt{234362} = 484.1094917
$$
We only want to go 50 units along the diagonal, so we figure out what fraction of the diagonal distance this constitutes. We have
$$
\frac{50}{484.1094917} = 0.10328242
$$
So, we need to go $0.10328242$ of the way along the diagonal from $A$; call it $0.1033$, for short. To do this, we should go $0.1033$ of the $x$-distance, and $0.1033$ of the $y$-distance.

So, our step in the $x$-direction should be $0.1033 \times 371$, which is $38.32$. Adding this to the $x$-coordinate of $A$, we get $50 + 38.32 = 88.32$.

Similarly, our step in the $y$-direction should be $0.1033 \times 311$, which is $32.12$. Adding this to the $y$-coordinate of $A$, we get $50 + 32.12 = 82.12$.

So, the desired point $B$ is at $x=88.32$, $y=82.12$ (roughly).

You could easily do all these calculations in Excel. Or, if you want code, it's as follows:

```
aX = 50   ;  aY = 50;
cX = 421  ;  cY = 361 ;

stepX = cX - aX;
stepY = cY - aY;

distance = sqrt(stepX*stepX + stepY*stepY);

fraction = 50/distance;

bX = aX + fraction*stepX;
bY = aY + fraction*stepY;
```

Comment: Thank you for a very broken down and easy to consume answer. The javascript helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, OK, I didn't realize it was that specific. Take the vector from $A$ to $C$, so in your case, $(421-50,361-50) = (371,311)$. We want to go $50$ units along there, so we move $$50\cdot\frac{(371,311)}{\sqrt{371^2+311^2}}$$ from the point $A$. So the answer is that your point $B$ is located at $$(50,50) + 50\cdot\frac{(371,311)}{\sqrt{371^2+311^2}} = (50,50)+(38.318,32.121) = (88.318,82.121).$$

**EDIT**: To go one unit along the line segment from $A$ to $C$ we move $371/{\sqrt{371^2+311^2}} = .76636$ in the first coordinate and $311/{\sqrt{371^2+311^2}} = .64242$ in the second coordinate. Thus, stretching by a factor of $50$ gives $38.318$ in the first coordinate and $32.121$ in the second coordinate. Now displace each by $50$ (the coordinates of $A$).

Comment: What does the mid dot after the 50 mean in this? Also (50,50) + 50 ? can this be done in two operations? Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: We're multiplying each of the entries of that fraction by $50$, and adding each to the terms in $(50,50)$. You should work it out on your calculator, and get the numbers I put. (The numbers 371 and 311 are pretty yucky.)

Comment: Sigh I don't understand how to read the symbols or how they are to be used. I am trying in my browser using javascript but having no luck getting the same numbers you are. If you could break this down into two separate calculations X and Y that could make things simpler for me.